# segmentation fault with scanf for const char*

Tags: c, string, pointers, constants

I have declared a variable as

```
const char* mode;
```

I want to get the value of `mode` from user. When I used

```
scanf("%s",mode)
```

I get a segmentation fault. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to allocate memory to the pointer to be able to do something meaningful with it. Declare it as:

```
#define MAX_LENGTH 256
char *mode = malloc(MAX_LENGTH);
```

Also, it is better to have stack allocation, if the memory needed is not too big:
simply,

```
char mode[MAX_LENGTH];
```

Comment: Hi Als, but I need to use const char* as I am passing this variable to a function. I cannot use just char* here.

Comment: You should be able to pass a `char*` to anything that wants a `const char*`, but not vice-versa.

Answer (score 5):

You *should* have gotten a warning on the `scanf` call.

By declaring

```
const char* mode;
```

you make `mode` a pointer to const char, which means you can't modify the data that `mode` points to.

Then you call:

```
scanf("%s",mode);
```

which attempts to modify the data that `mode` points to.

gcc warns about this:

```
warning: writing into constant object (argument 2) [-Wformat]
```

So `mode` needs to be a pointer to *non-const* char.  And, as others have mentioned, it needs to point to some actual data so that `scanf` can modify that data.  That's probably what's causing your segmentation fault, but since you haven't shown us how `mode` is initialized, it's difficult to tell.

`mode` will normally point to the first character of an array.  So how big does that array have to be?  Since you're using `scanf` with a `"%s"` format, it can't possibly be big enough.  `scanf("%s", mode)` reads a whitespace-delimited string from `stdin` into the buffer pointed to by `mode`.  You can't avoid input that will overflow the buffer.

(If this is a beginner's exercise, you can probably ignore the buffer overflow issue *for now*; just make `mode` point to a buffer that's reasonably big, and avoid providing very long input.)

Comment: +1: For taking out time to answer and explain in detail instead of just giving an answer like I did.

Answer (score 2):

A segmentation fault  is generally an attempt to access memory that the CPU cannot physically address. 
That is because u have not allocated memory for your variable. 
Note:
But some c compiler like Turbo C++ allows you to do so without even allocating memory.

Comment: even Turbo C code will encounter trouble with uninitialized pointers, though in x86 *real mode*, it does not cause a segfault:  some random memory is corrupted.